# Add Mmenu to Laravel using NPM

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8, mmenu

I'm trying to add mmenu.js to a Laravel 8 project. I've installed it using NPM, but I'm having trouble including it in the project.

Right now, in bootstrap.js I have this:

```
import Mmenu from 'mmenu-js';
window.Mmenu = Mmenu;
```

There's no detailed documentation on the site for how to install on Laravel, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can include in your project by writing code in the head section of page.
Following is the example to put menu in your project.

```
    <link href="path/to/css/mmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="path/to/js/mmenu.js"></script>

    <!-- Fire the plugin -->
    <script>
        document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                new Mmenu( "#my-menu" );
            }
        );
    </script>
```